# Fluentvalidation PropertyNameResolver issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I have an ASP.net MVC 5 application that uses Fluentvalidation. It works fine, however I am experiencing a problem when trying to define my own PropertyNameResolver to wrap all property names in single quotes. In other words, I want the error message to be "'Name' is required" instead of "Name is required". This should be possible to do for all messages using the PropertyNameResolver.

When I define my own PropertyNameResolver, no error messages displayed. If I do not set my own PropertyNameResolver, error messages are displayed, but without the quotes, obviously.

The validation rules are all of type NotEmpty. I am thinking that since these are run client side, there may be an issue when defining my own PropertyNameResolver. Maybe someone can verify this?

Test Code:

```
ValidatorOptions.PropertyNameResolver = PropertyNameResolver;

private string PropertyNameResolver(Type type, MemberInfo memberInfo, LambdaExpression arg3)
{
    if (memberInfo != null)
    {
        return "'" + memberInfo.Name + "'";
    }
    return null;

 }
```

Comment: did you get this fixed? I don't the answer myself, but wanting to user the ProperyNameResolver and don't know where to put the code similar to yours. In an AbstractValidator?

Comment: no it is not fixed